# Laravel ошибка Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class 'App\Http\Controllers\name' not found

Tags: php

PHP - 7.2.34 
 laravel - 6.2

```
public function basketConfirm(Request $request){
        $orderId = session('orderId');
        if (is_null($orderId)){
            return redirect()->route('index');
    } 
        $order = Order::find('orderId');
        $order = new name;
        $order->name = $request->name;
        $order->phone = $request->phone;
        $order->status = 1;
        $order->save();
        return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Говорит что такая ошибка 
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\name' not found

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку исправил, немного поменяв и переместив код. 
Эту часть кода я оставил в BasketController.php

```
public function basketConfirm(Request $request)
{
    $orderId = session('orderId');
    if (is_null($orderId)) {
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
    $order = Order::find($orderId);
    $success = $order->saveOrder($request->name, $request->phone);

    if ($success) {
        session()->flash('success', 'Ваш заказ принят в обработку!');
    } else {
        session()->flash('warning', 'Случилась ошибка');
    }

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

А эту часть кода переместил из контролера в Order.php

```
public function saveOrder($name, $phone)
{
    if ($this->status == 0) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->status = 1;
        $this->save();
        session()->forget('orderId');
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```